# Google Analytics in iOS, How do I know if a page of my website was opened using an app?

Tags: ios, events, google-analytics, tracking, referrals

I'm developing an iOS app that required me to track a clicked event on an advertising image.
When user clicked on the ads image the app will open a website in web view. My question is : how does the owner of that website know that the website has been opened from a link in my app ?

Comment: What does this have to do with GoogleAnalytics?

Comment: I am using google analytics to track how user re-act on the ads. I have the full report to myself, but my client also want to know the traffic from my app in order for them to be sure that their return investment is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. In case someone wants to do the same as mine, I've added this "?utm_campaign=August&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=MyApp" at the end of the link when clicked. So when the ads owner opens their google analytics console they will see in referral tab the traffic from MyApp. Here is the [link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en-GB) for GA detail.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you want to know whether the user clicked the add and the webview was opened, and the add was completely loaded? You could try adding Google Analytics via Javascript to the ad web page or you could use the **webViewDidFinishLoad** method in the webview to track whether the add was loaded completely or not.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply @satheeshwaran. In fact it should be about the referral measurement that the ads' owner has to put by themselves.